# Read paradox DBF files and import in H2 database

Tags: java, database, import, h2, paradox

can i import DBF files (i think it is files of paradox database) into H2 database?

I think a good solution is to write a small wrapper in java to read dbf data and save in h2 database, there is a jdbc driver to use paradox with java?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paradox files are not DBF. These belong to dBASE. I think Paradox files have a .DB extension. In any case, whether the files you are working with belong to Paradox or dBASE, you can easily convert the data into a format H2 can import. Your solution would work.

Comment: Thank you, so there is a driver to connect to dBase database from java?

ps. file *.DBF are tables of one database or are databases file?

Comment: Im using paradox-dbase-reader software to read dbf data, its seems to be tables.
The problems is i have a abc.DBF and abc.MDF files, and the software can't read abc.BDF file, i think the problem is this file need the file abc.MDF, isn't true?
Thank again.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for converting the `.DBF` files to `.SQL` script (with `CREATE`s and `INSERT`s). It seems to pretty much software on the Internet which could help. I haven't used any of these, so I can't suggest a particular one.